# How can I set set the values of a MatrixView to the values of a vector of the same size?

Tags: rust, nalgebra

I have for example an `SVector<f64, 10>` to store data. While going over a loop I want to replace sections of length `2` in this vector with the values of a `SVector<f64, 2>`.

```rust
let a = SVector::<f64, 10>::default();

for i in 0..5 {
    let newvec = SVector::<f64, 2>::new(1.0, 2.0); 

    a.fixed_rows_mut::<2>(2 * i) = newvec; // why does this not work?

}
```

I basically have a large vector and need to set elements to certain values.
Since `fixed_rows_mut` exists I would imagine this is the way to do it.

Reading the Docs I didn't find another obvious way to do it.

Edit: I fixed an error and another one so that this example can be used directly.

Edit: Here the error message:

```
error[E0070]: invalid left-hand side of assignment
 --> src/main.rs:9:38
  |
9 |         a.fixed_rows_mut::<2>(2 * i) = newvec;
  |         ---------------------------- ^
  |         |
  |         cannot assign to this expression

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0070`.
error: could not compile `playground` (bin "playground") due to previous error
```

and a [playground link.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d2a357b780a64b3c7e0f3a0cdf56dc33)

Comment: What is `grad` in the loop? Should that be `a` instead?

Comment: How does it not work? A compile time error? Please show the full error from `cargo check`. A runtime panic? Please post the panic message. Does not produce the expected results? Please post the produced and the expected result.

Comment: oh sorry yes of course. : (  there's always something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign a matrix to another matrix directly (which is what you are trying to do with `a.fixed_rows_mut::<2>(2 * i) = newvec;`). What you can do is assign the *contents* of your left-hand matrix to the *contents* of the right-hand matrix. To do that, you have to dereference both the left-hand side and the right-hand side of the assignment:

```rust
for i in 0..5 {
    let newvec = SVector::<f64, 2>::new(1.0, 2.0);

    *a.fixed_rows_mut::<2>(2 * i) = *newvec;
}
```

[Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7ba2594042b2b7e9f5ca5f75e91ad4ff)

Comment: Oh nice! Thank you very much!
I didn't think about dereferencing *both* sides of the assignment. That works nicely! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have a follow-up question now:
Within my loop I want to use the value `newvec` two times (in my code I have two nested loops where I calculate something. But the calculated `value(i,j)` is the same as `-1.0 * value(j,i)`. So I would like to use newtec 2 times and assign it to another view.
But I cannot understand how I can Add. `+=` instead of the `=` doesn't work.

Comment: You mean like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e69c0a82da0f4e660d03256f3112ea4e)?

Comment: Yes exactly like this - thanks again! I don't understand why I didn't find this out myself - I tried out almost all combinations. Since many implementations are within macros it's difficult to understand directly (and quickly) unfortunately. A better representation of what I want to do is [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=44f0e50a746cf406f305e2c2e347306d)